# Getting a holed shapefile

Tags: arcmap, shapefile

I have two shapefiles the red one is the urban areas, the green is the agricultural land and the dark green represents forest. I want to remove the surface of the red shapefile from the green shapefile in order to calculate the exact surface of the green shapefile (agricultural land).
Do anyone have any solution?

[image]

Comment: Erase tool: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/erase.htm

Comment: You could also use Intersect or Union

Comment: Or the [clip tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/editing/clip-features-using-another-feature.htm) to manually remove the red area from the underlying green area.